# Restrict email pattern to specific domains

Tags: java, regex

i am using the following email pattern:

```
[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]@[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]
```

and i want to restrict it to allow specific domains like: .com, .org, .net, .edu

how to accomplish that, please advise.

Comment: It's in the last part: `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]`

Comment: make a group from the domain match and check it agains the once you want ?

Comment: Why? There aren't many reasons to do this. If you need to make sure it's a valid email, the best way is to try to send a confirmation email to it. And as someone with [first]@[last].me and normal @gmail.com addresses, I wouldn't sign up for your site if it didn't let me use `+` in my email address, or let me use @example.me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]@[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.(com|org|net|edu)`

You probably want to compile this with a case insensitive flag, or add uppercase versions of the e-mail address endings you want.

Answer (score -2):

For .com

```
[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]@[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]\.com
```

For any of .com, .org, .net, .edu

```
[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]@[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]\.(com|org|net|edu)
```

Comment: -1 doesn't work correctly. It matches foo@bar.baz.com but not foo@bar.com.

Comment: @dogbane, what do you suggest ?